# After changing project location , SHA1 is not working

Tags: google-play

I have updated my application for 5 times in Google, recently, I have deleted all my project files, and restore them back from backup.(I have my .JKS file and password) but, now - I cannot upload updated application to Store. It has different SHA1.

This problem appears after manipulating with files, or my .JKS is incorrect?

Thank you

Comment: I've checked, that my .jks has same sha1 as google asked.. but when do signing from Android Studio - google play rejects.. it was strange. I simply restarted IDE and signin again == worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked, that my .jks has same sha1 as google asked.. but when do signing from Android Studio - google play rejects.. it was strange. I simply restarted IDE and signin again == worked.